# How to clear the content of .log file programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa, logging, nslog

In my application, i have logged the details of the application in project.log with the help of  following code.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *logPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"project.log"];
freopen([logPath fileSystemRepresentation],"a+",stderr);
```

This code will perfectly log all the details that i defined in nslog.  Now i don't want my log file to grow much further. So i want to clear the content of log files that was logged before 1 week or more. But i need the content of log for last 7 days. Is there any possible solution to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy solution. It's not exactly what you have asked, but maybe it's valuable to you.

On startup, do this:

- check if `project.log` exists and is greater than (e.g.) 2MB.
- If no, just use `project.log`.
- If yes: 1) remove `project.old.log` if it exists. 2) rename `project.log` to `project.old.log` 3) log to `project.log` (it will be created if you open with "a+")

Comment: Thanks. but i want to clear the log for certain time period(from beginning to a week before).

Comment: then you have to just clear it. parse the log. find the first log line that is in your time frame. write all the following log lines into the new file. delete the old file. rename the new file. there is no shortcut.

Comment: I have checked all the possibilities. No other way. Thanks for your answer. Implemented this logic.